# Why is GHCi typing this statement oddly?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typing, ghci

In answering a question on stackoverflow, I noticed that GHCi (interactive) is assigning a too-restrictive type in a **let** statement. Namely, given the code,

```
import Control.Arrow
f = maximum &&& id >>> fst &&& (\(m,l) -> length $ filter (==m) l)
```

(as on my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281813/maximum-of-list-and-count-of-repeat-maximum-number/6283594#6283594), if one inserts a "let" before `f` and enters this in ghci, it gives the following type information

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> :t f
f :: [()] -> ((), Int)
```

whereas just asking for the type of the expression gives the correct result, namely `Ord a => [a] -> (a, Int)`. I'm using ghc 7.0.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [extended defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) used in GHCi for an explanation of where the `()` is coming from.

As for why the defaulting occurs in this case, compare the following:

```
> let f x = maximum &&& id >>> fst &&& (\(m,l) -> length $ filter (==m) l) $ x
> :t f
f :: (Ord a) => [a] -> (a, Int)
```

I assume this has something to do with bindings being monomorphic, but I'm not certain of the details.

Comment: Indeed it does. Running GHCi with `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` gives the same result.

Comment: @hammar: Thanks, good catch! For some reason it didn't occur to me to try that and I wasn't sure whether GHCi might have other special behavior for bindings in the REPL.